# Search for a String and replace string in above line

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed, xml-parsing

I have a gigantic XML file and need to change a few 100 lines that occur above a line that I know about.

```
<errorCode>4544</errorCode>
<severity>4</severity>
<modelDescription>Licensing: Invalid license</modelDescription>
```

I want to grep for "Licensing: Invalid license" and change the "4" above it or any other number.

Im trying to do something like:

```
sed -i '/Invalid license/{n;s/4/6/;}' file
```

but it did not work. Any suggestions how I can grep for a pattern and then change a value above it ?

Comment: Please don't use terms like "gigantic". Use numbers (we're engineers after all). It might well affect the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use SED for XML parsing, since it is not designed to handle XML syntax, and writing an XML parser in SED is a difficult task. Besides, there are many useful tools exactly for this purpose.

Consider this XML:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <errorCode>4000</errorCode>
    <severity>2</severity>
    <modelDescription>Some error</modelDescription>
  </item>
  <item>
    <errorCode>4544</errorCode>
    <severity>4</severity>
    <modelDescription>Licensing: Invalid license</modelDescription>
  </item>
</root>
```

You can easily modify the `severity` value with [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//item[severity = 4
and modelDescription = "Licensing: Invalid license"]/severity' \
  -v 100 file.xml
```

The command updates (`-u`) the value of `severity` element by replacing the original value (`4`) with `100`. The XPath expression selects `severity` elements for all `item` elements having `severity` child with value `4` and `modelDescription` child with value `Licensing: Invalid license`.

The result is printed to the standard output. To edit the file in-place, use `--inplace` option: `xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u ...`.

*Output*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <errorCode>4000</errorCode>
    <severity>2</severity>
    <modelDescription>Some error</modelDescription>
  </item>
  <item>
    <errorCode>4544</errorCode>
    <severity>100</severity>
    <modelDescription>Licensing: Invalid license</modelDescription>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous line and check current line if it matches your pattern. If so, modify previous line and print, otherwise, print as such. Please see the below:

```
while IFS= read line
do
    echo $line | grep "<severity>[0-9]</severity>" > /dev/null && { 
        sev=$line
    } || {
        echo $line | grep "Invalid license" > /dev/null && {
            echo $sev | sed "s/4/5/"
        } || {
            if [ ! -z $sev ]; then echo $sev; fi
        }
        sev=""
        echo $line
    }
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation that does the job, assuming the elements you show are wrapped in an item element:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="c" streamable="no" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of(.)" mode="c"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="c"
  match="severity[following-sibling::modelDescription=
                    'Licensing: Invalid license']">
  <severity>6</severity>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The item elements have to be copied before being processed because you want to "look ahead" when processing the severity element, and that can't be done in streaming mode.

Answer (score 0):

This could help

```
sed -i.bak '/Invalid license/!{x;1!p;d;};x;s/4/6' <file path>
```